# Meaning of fields in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am self learning QFT and I am stuck on some interpretation.

What does the quantity that denotes the field say, $\phi(t,\vec{x})$, really mean? How is it different from a similar quantity describing a point mass?

Comment: maybe this related answer of mine helps  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256663/   and  this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308413/

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/337423/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155608/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13157/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You have asked like 6 very simple questions in the last few days. Can I suggest you spend a little bit more time on finding answers yourself rather than bother the PSE community for every triviality that is not immediately obvious to you? @thomas